# Message Box in IronPython with WPF

Tags: python, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2017, ironpython

I'm trying to create a simple GUI using WPF in VS2017. I've tried following code to show a MessageBox after clicking generate button:

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import MessageBox
def generate_Btn_Click(self, sender, e):
   MessageBox.Show("hi")
```

and it will show up if I click on the generate button but, if I try to add an if statement before `MessageBox.Show()`:

```
def generate_Btn_Click(self, sender, e):
    if A == None: 
        MessageBox.Show("Message1!")
    else:
        MessageBox.Show("Message2!")
```

after clicking on generate button, no MessageBox appears and the window closes. My question is how to use MessageBox In IronPython using WPF.
A simple example that will not work when I push the button is as follows:

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import MessageBox
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'IronPython5.xaml')
    str1 = ""
    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
        if str1 == "":
            MessageBox.Show("msg1")
        else:
            MessageBox.Show("msg2")

        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

This is the XAML:

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="IronPython5" Height="300" Width="300"> 
       <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,238,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `if A == None:` the A may throw an error unless it refers to something in your code ?

Comment: @PRMoureu it refers to a variable and is valid. I deleted extra codes to make it clean. I use A in other parts of code and is ok.

Comment: is `A` a global variable?

Comment: @denfromufa it's a member of class defined for current project and is initialized to None

Comment: then you need to show your method within the class and how it is instantiated. currently your code would not run and is not reproducible. i bet if you start your app from cmd, then some error would show up in the console for the second case.

Comment: @denfromufa I've updated the post for a whole class definition that doesn't work.

Comment: you have not included your xaml file

Comment: @denfromufa I put the XAML in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran from cmd, here is the error I got:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7>ipy wpfapp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wpfapp.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "wpfapp.py", line 10, in Button_Click
NameError: global name 'str1' is not defined
```

You cannot define global variables inside class!

And now here is a quick fix for you:

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import MessageBox
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.str1 = ""
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'app.xaml')
    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
        if self.str1 == "":
            MessageBox.Show("msg1")
        else:
            MessageBox.Show("msg2")

        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works fine! please let me know how did you started the code using ipy.exe? is it actually necessary to put both XAML and python code in ipy.exe directory and then run it? I don't know how to run the IronPython projects created by VS using the commad line.